# Перебрать массив объектов с ключами

Tags: javascript

Есть массив `Users`, который состоит из n объектов.

```
let users = [
{
    idu: 'btI3E8AHH0ct80V5nwvVBfXnCDh2', name: 'Илья', score: 10
},
{
    idu: 'btI3E8AHH0ct80V5nwvVBfXnCDh2', name: 'Илья', score: 15
},
{
    idu: '45gtGXaFghNc3x3n7WFFd5etSfS2', name: 'Петя', score: 6
},
{
    idu: '45gtGXaFghNc3x3n7WFFd5etSfS2', name: Петя, score: 2
}
]
```

Необходимо сложить `score` у каждого отдельного юзера.
Ожидаемый результат - массив с объектами

```
{
    idu: 'btI3E8AHH0ct80V5nwvVBfXnCDh2', name: 'Илья', score: 25
},
{
    idu: '45gtGXaFghNc3x3n7WFFd5etSfS2', name: 'Петя', score: 8
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: Вы что-нибудь слышали про циклы?

Comment: Да, но не хватает знаний.

Comment: Может быть, прочитать знания?

Comment: Вполне вероятно, но тогда бы я не пришел сюда.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects

Comment: @Maxim покажите (добавьте в сам вопрос), как вы пробовали решить данную задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вам нужно объединить массив объектов на основании какого-то ключа, удобнее всего использовать временный объект со значениями этого ключа, а потом просто превратить его в массив его значений. Например, так:

```js
let users = [
  {
      idu: 'btI3E8AHH0ct80V5nwvVBfXnCDh2', name: 'Илья', score: 10
  },
  {
      idu: 'btI3E8AHH0ct80V5nwvVBfXnCDh2', name: 'Илья', score: 15
  },
  {
      idu: '45gtGXaFghNc3x3n7WFFd5etSfS2', name: 'Петя', score: 6
  },
  {
      idu: '45gtGXaFghNc3x3n7WFFd5etSfS2', name: 'Петя', score: 2
  }
];

const usersSum = Object.values(users.reduce(
  (acc, { idu, name, score }) => {
    acc[idu] ??= { idu, name, score: 0 };
    acc[idu].score += score;
    return acc;
  },
  {},
));

console.log(usersSum);
```

Или чуть более развёрнуто:

```js
let users = [
  {
      idu: 'btI3E8AHH0ct80V5nwvVBfXnCDh2', name: 'Илья', score: 10
  },
  {
      idu: 'btI3E8AHH0ct80V5nwvVBfXnCDh2', name: 'Илья', score: 15
  },
  {
      idu: '45gtGXaFghNc3x3n7WFFd5etSfS2', name: 'Петя', score: 6
  },
  {
      idu: '45gtGXaFghNc3x3n7WFFd5etSfS2', name: 'Петя', score: 2
  }
];

const temp = {};

for (const user of users) {
  if (!temp[user.idu]) temp[user.idu] = { idu: user.idu, name: user.name, score: 0 };
  temp[user.idu].score += user.score;
}

const usersSum = Object.values(temp);

console.log(usersSum);
```

Comment: Огромная благодарность!

Comment: @Maxim Я добавил менее сокращённый вариант.